# Accessing ModelAndView in postHandle() interferes with response output stream

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am encountering the weirdest issue.

I have a subclass of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` with `postHandle()`. Regardless of other code, if I add the following line to the interceptor, the dispatcher servlet eventually fails with `getOutputStream() has already been called for this response` error.

```
boolean isRedirect = modelAndView.getViewName().startsWith("redirect:");
```

It seems as if accessing `view` in `modelAndView` somehow interfered with response output stream. I am baffled. Anybody any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have an exception in your controller. try to surround it with try/catch and log exception